# Adding Clients as internal testers to show app preview in TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Is it a good idea to use TestFlight internal testers option to show app preview to clients adding them as technicians with their own AppleID?

It's fast an easy.. but..? there is allways a but..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [HockeyAPP](http://hockeyapp.net/)

Its faster, but you need to register the client device UDID.

I had a problema adding a friend to my itunes connect account. When he tried to enroll for his own account was not possible because he already was linked to my account with his apple id.